# Java Optional: Alter value

Tags: java, option-type

I am using Java Optionals.

```
String in = "sam";
String ret = Optional.ofNullable (in).orElse ("NULL");  // "sam"
in = null;
ret = Optional.ofNullable (in).orElse ("NULL");         // "NULL"
```

Is it possible to extend my optional to return an altered value if it is not null?

Lets say `"#sam#"` instead of `"sam"` and `"NULL"` in case of `null`.

If I already change in to

```
in = "#" + in + "#"
```

it would never be `null` and in case of `in == null` it would return `"#null#"` instead of `"NULL"`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `map`:

```
String ret = Optional.ofNullable (in).map(s->'#'+s+'#').orElse ("NULL");
```